# Condition with a relationship eloquent

Tags: laravel

Hello Im a beginer with Laravel 
Im trying to retrieve the data using eloquent but I have to add a condition linked to a relationship 
my model

```
class DemandeInscription extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','tuteur_id');
    }
}
```

And here is what I tried in my Controller

```
$demandes= DemandeInscription::with('user','meet','enfant')
           ->where('confirmation','=',0)->user()
           ->where('phone_verified_at','!=',null)
           ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

i get the error

```
Arguments
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::user()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well you can get it in this way

```
$demandes= DemandeInscription::with(['user' => function($query){
              $query->where('phone_verified_at','!=',null);
           },'meet','enfant'])
           ->where('confirmation','=',0)
           ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

OR

```
$demandes= DemandeInscription::whereHas(['user' => function($query){
              $query->where('phone_verified_at','!=',null);
           }])
           ->orwhereHas('meet','enfant')
           ->where('confirmation','=',0)
           ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

OR with Local Scope, inside `User Model` write this scope

```
public function scopeVerified($query){
   return $query->where('phone_verified_at','!=',null);
}

$demandes= DemandeInscription::with(['user' => function($query){
              $query->verified();
           },'meet','enfant'])
           ->where('confirmation','=',0)
           ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer so that other can get help too :) ?